# Xperia Z5 Compact not visible in adb

Tags: adb

I got two android devices: Nexus 7 and Xperia Z5 Compact. Both of them are easily find by adb on my local computer, but I usually work on my notebook, and here comes the problem. Both my devices couldn't be found. I reinstalled SDK and installed Google USB Drivers. Then I reinstalled drivers of my Nexus to Google drivers and Nexus is visible for ADB. But I cannot do this for Xperia. When I try to update my drivers, it says the best one are already in (MTP USB device).

My OS is Windows 7 on notebook and Windows 10 on local computer.

Any ideas how to make Sony's child visible?